# martingale representation of two independent Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, filtrations

Let $W^1_t$ and $W^2_t$ be two independent standard Brownian motions. Then $W^2_t$ is a martingale with respect to the its own filtration but not adapted to the filtration generated by $W^1_t$.
I want to proof this. I have to show:
There cannot be an Ito integrand $H$ such that

$$W_t^2=\int_0^t H dW^1_s$$

Applying Ito's formula on $W_t^1W_t^2$ yields:

$$W_t^1W_t^2=\int_0^t W_s^2 dW^1_s +\int_0^t W_s^1 dW^2_s $$

How can I make my argument from here on rigious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $W_{2,t}$ is a martingale wrt $\mathcal{F}^{W_2}_s:=\sigma(\{W_{2,h},h\leq s\})$ for $s<t$ we see that, since $W_{2,t}-W_{2,s}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,t-s)$ is independent from $\mathcal{F}^{W_2}_s$ and $W_{2,s}$ is $\mathcal{F}^{W_2}_s$-measurable so it can be 'taken out' from the conditional expectation we get
$$E[W_{2,t}|\mathcal{F}^{W_2}_s]=E[(W_{2,t}-W_{2,s})+W_{2,s}|\mathcal{F}^{W_2}_s]=W_{2,s}E[1|\mathcal{F}^{W_2}_s]=W_{2,s}$$
To see that $W_{2,t}$ is not a $\mathcal{F}_t^{W_1}$-martingale, since $W_{2,s}$ is independent from $W_{1,s}$ we get
$$E[W_{2,t}|\mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}]=E[W_{2,s}|\mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}]=E[W_{2,s}]=0$$
which is not a.s. equal to $W_{2,s}$. Indeed for $A \in \mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}$
$$\begin{aligned}E[E[W_{2,s}|\mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}]\mathbb{I}_A]&=E[W_{2,s}\mathbb{I}_A]=\\&=E[W_{2,s}]E[\mathbb{I}_A]=\\
&=E[E[W_{2,s}]\mathbb{I}_A]\end{aligned}$$
so $E[W_{2,s}|\mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}]=E[W_{2,s}]=0$ a.s.

Comment: $$E[W_{2,t}|\mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}]=E[W_{2,s}|\mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}]=E[W_{2,s}]=0$$ Why is the time index s in the second step,i.e. $W_{2,s}$

Comment: @Sarah 
$$E[W_{2,t}|\mathcal{F}^{W_1}_s]=E[(W_{2,t}-W_{2,s})+W_{2,s}|\mathcal{F}^{W_1}_s]=E[W_{2,s}|\mathcal{F}^{W_1}_s]$$

Comment: Thank you very much.  Is $E[W_{2,t}|\mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}]=E[W_{2,s}|\mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}]=E[W_{2,s}]=0$ not sufficient for my claim. What do you want to argue for after that

Comment: @Sarah I thought you wanted to show that $W_{2,t}$ is not a $\mathcal{F}^{W_1}_t$-martingale

Comment: But this $$E[W_{2,t}|\mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}]=E[W_{2,s}|\mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}]=E[W_{2,s}]=0$$ already verifies that $W_{2,t}$ is not a $F_{t}^{W_1}$ martingale?

Comment: I think we could argue like this:
$$W_{2,t}\textrm{ is a }\mathcal{F}_t^{W_1}\textrm{-martingale} \implies E[W_{2,t}|\mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}]=W_{2,s}\textrm{ a.s.}$$
$$E[W_{2,t}|\mathcal{F}_s^{W_1}]\neq W_{2,s}\textrm{ a.s.} \implies W_{2,t}\textrm{ is not a }\mathcal{F}_t^{W_1}\textrm{-martingale}$$
what do you think?

Comment: Yes I think so too. Thank you for the clear view on this.

Comment: Just for clarification. If my filtration is generated by $W_1,W_2$ both of them are matringales. Let us assume that $B= a W_2 + \sqrt{1-a^2} W_3$, where $W_2,W_3$ are again independent BM. Are $W_1,W_2$ still martingales, if my filtration is generated by $W_1, B$

Comment: @Sarah you're welcome. you should post another question for the case with $B$

Comment: Ok I will do that. Maybe a simple yes or no can give me the right hint.